# Subset from xpath query?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML that looks roughly as follows:

```
<Dispatch ID = "JJJJ">
    <Log ID = "150504BCFSP00072">
        <LogTime>"May  4 2015  5:48PM"</LogTime>
        <LogType>"1125-KKKK"</LogType>
        <LogDetails>
            <details>
                <DetailTime>"May  4 2015  5:48PM"</DetailTime>
                <IncidentDetail>"[1] The Thing I Want"</IncidentDetail>
                 <DetailTime>"May  4 2015  5:49PM"</DetailTime> 
                <IncidentDetail>"[2] The Thing I Don't Want"</IncidentDetail>
            </details>
         </LogDetails>
    </Log>
</Dispatch>
```

I want to extract all IncidentDetail text from the log where the Station ID is JJJJ, & where its LogType contains "KKKK", and its IncidentDetail starts with [1] (making it the first update of potentially many). So far I have this XPATH query:

```
//Dispatch[@ID='JJJJ']//Log/LogType[contains(.,'KKKK')]
```

This gets me a list of incidents, as follows:

```
Element='<LogType>"1125-KKKK"</LogType>'
Element='<LogType>"1125-KKKK"</LogType>'
Element='<LogType>"1125-KKKK"</LogType>'
```

But that's only got me in a rathole. How do I go backward now and get the IncidentDetail text for each of these LogType incidents that match what I'm looking for? Is there some multi-step process?

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of stepping to `Log/LogType` in the main axis, you can put it as predicate like this :

```
//Dispatch[@ID='JJJJ'][Log/LogType[contains(.,'KKKK')]]
```

or another way :

```
//Dispatch[@ID='JJJJ' and Log/LogType[contains(.,'KKKK')]]
```

From here, you can easily continue the main axis to get to `IncidentDetail` without having to go backward whatsoever :

```
/Log/LogDetails/details/IncidentDetail
```

**Regarding the updates :**

You can add filter to get only the first `IncindentDetail` within the same parent either by using xpath index :

```
/Log/LogDetails/details/IncidentDetail[1]
```

or filtering by the node's text content :

```
/Log/LogDetails/details/IncidentDetail[contains(.,'[1]')
```

Comment: Okay, that nearly has me there. I now have:

    //Dispatch[@ID='JJJJ' and Log/LogType[contains(.,'KKKK')] and Log/LogDetails/details/IncidentDetail[contains(.,'[1]')]]//LogDetails/details/IncidentDetail

The trouble is, this doesn't filter on the final '[1]' criteria. Note that I added that third filter criteria just now, because I only need IncidentDetails where they contain a [1], denoting that they're the first of that particular kind, if that makes sense (i.e, not an incident update).

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you mean something like `<IncidentDetail>[1]..bla..bla..</IncidentDetail>` simply the first `<IncidentDetail>` node? If you meant the latter, then it should've been : `...../IncidentDetail[1]` instead

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. And I have tried what you just described, and it's still not filtering for that condition. Really puzzling. Typical would be something like this:

<IncidentDetail>"[1] BLK BLK KKKS SKJDFHJH ETC"</IncidentDetail>

And there are often multiple such updates, numbered sequentially, but I just want the first one. Can't get ...../IncidentDetail[1] to filter for that condition. 

Thanks for your help. I'll keep tinkering.

Comment: I suspect that's because all `IncidentDetail` are in the same `Dispatch` ancestor. So filtering the `Dispatch` node won't help. You should've added the filter for `IncidentDetail` node instead, something like this : `//Dispatch[@ID='JJJJ' and Log/LogType[contains(.,'KKKK')]]/Log/LogDetails/details/IncidentDetail[contains(.,'[1]')]`

Comment: Can I just add one more question: Say I also wanted the unique Log ID of each incident for which all of the above filters applied, can I somehow do a lookback union and get that too? In other words, I want it to return two values: 

1) The text of the IncidentDetail for "{1]".
2) The ID of that overall Incident, as show in Log ID.

How do I work backwards to get that ID for the specific IncidentDetail, given the filters applied?

Comment: I'd suggest to post a new question as these comments can be confusing for future visitor to follow (and even for me later on). Also, what's vivid clear to me is the original question. The further you add to it, the less I can understand you. Starting over with sample XML, and the expected output would really help to clear things up.

Comment: f.e. I didn't clearly understand your 2nd comment until sample XML in question updated. Anyway, keep changing question will also be confusing

Answer (score 0):

Try `//Dispatch[@ID='JJJJ']//Log/LogType[contains(.,'KKKK')]//IncidentDetail`.