# Extract multiple values in single XPATH query?

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to extract two pieces of data from XML similar to the following. 
**First**, I need all IncidentDetail text where the Dispatch ID is "JJJJ", the LogType is "KKKK", and the IncidentDetail itself contains the text "[Subset from xpath query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042889/subset-from-xpath-query)". 
**Second**, I need the Log ID string for any incidents containing such events.

```
<Dispatch ID = "JJJJ">
<Log ID = "150504BCFSP00072">
    <LogTime>"May  4 2015  5:48PM"</LogTime>
    <LogType>"1125-KKKK"</LogType>
    <LogDetails>
        <details>
            <DetailTime>"May  4 2015  5:48PM"</DetailTime>
            <IncidentDetail>"[1] The Thing I Want"</IncidentDetail>
             <DetailTime>"May  4 2015  5:49PM"</DetailTime> 
            <IncidentDetail>"[2] The Thing I Don't Want"</IncidentDetail>
        </details>
     </LogDetails>
</Log>
<Log ID = "250504BCFSP00072">
    <LogTime>"May  5 2015  5:48PM"</LogTime>
    <LogType>"1125-MMMM"</LogType>
    <LogDetails>
        <details>
            <DetailTime>"May  5 2015  5:48PM"</DetailTime>
            <IncidentDetail>"[1] A Thing I Don't Want"</IncidentDetail>
             <DetailTime>"May  5 2015  5:49PM"</DetailTime> 
            <IncidentDetail>"[2] A Thing I Don't Want"</IncidentDetail>
        </details>
     </LogDetails>
</Log>
<Log ID = "350504BCFSP00072">
    <LogTime>"May  6 2015  5:48PM"</LogTime>
    <LogType>"1125-KKKK"</LogType>
    <LogDetails>
        <details>
            <DetailTime>"May  6 2015  5:48PM"</DetailTime>
            <IncidentDetail>"[1] Another Thing I Want"</IncidentDetail>
             <DetailTime>"May  6 2015  5:49PM"</DetailTime> 
            <IncidentDetail>"[2] Another Thing I Don't Want"</IncidentDetail>
        </details>
     </LogDetails>
</Log>
</Dispatch>
```

The following XPATH query satisfies the first condition. It extracts the IncidentDetail for incidents where condition 1) above is true. (Original discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042889/subset-from-xpath-query).)

```
//Dispatch[@ID='JJJJ' and Log/LogType[contains(.,'KKKK')]]/Log/LogDetails/details/IncidentDetail[contains(.,'[1]')]
```

Now I need the unique Log ID for each such case. In this substring of XML, I'd want "150504BCFSP00072". In the full XML there can be many incidents logged, so many Log IDs, only some of which contain incidents that match the three filters I described above. In other words, only certain Log IDs need to be extracted and matched up with IncidentDetail strings.

The actual output would, I'd hope, look something like the following:

```
<IncidentDetail>"[1] The Thing I Want"</IncidentDetail>
<Log ID = "150504BCFSP00072">
<IncidentDetail>"[1] Another Thing I Want"<IncidentDetail>
<Log ID = "350504BCFSP00072">
etc.
```

How might I do the second extraction and somehow union it with results of the first XPATH query? Apologies in advance for my somewhat garbled question syntax. I'm relatively new to XPATH, and I'm still sorting out what's possible, what's not, and how you ask about it.

Comment: XPath is for *selection*, not *manipulation*.  If you want to manipulate or transform that which you've selected, use XPath within a hosting language such as XSLT (ideal), Python, Java, etc and do the manipulation/transformation in the hosting language.

Comment: Also, state specifically the desired output using an example.  For simple assembly such as concatenation, you might be able to use a single XPath expression that combines two selection paths, but generally you'll want XSLT or another language as mentioned above for any but the most elementary of manipulations.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize I was manipulating -- I thought this was just selecting. Specifically, I want all IncidentDetail text matching one set of criteria, and the Log IDs for all those incidents. Will update with desired output.

Comment: XPath selects flat lists of nodes (node-sets) that have no hierarchical context and must occur as they are in the input. So trying to select `<Log ID = "350504BCFSP00072" />` (a node that is not in the input in this form) amounts to manipulating the input. XPath is inherently incapable of doing that. XQuery would be able to do that, or XSLT, or .NET's Linq, or "manually" traversing the DOM in the host language and constructing an output document.